# What adapter do I need to mount an MTO-11CA 1000mm on a Nikon DSLR?

Tags: lens, nikon, old-lenses, adapter

I have a Nikon D5500 and an old MTO-11CA 1000mm mirror lens. Here's a picture of the lens mount:

[image: image of lens mount]

What adapters and extension adapter would I need? It's M39

Comment: I bought M42 adapter, it works fine with Helios lenses, but it's too big for MTO lens, So I need a smaller adapter and I don't know which one do I need to buy and I think that I need some kind of extension adapter too

Comment: @Pranjuo Please add the solution as an answer rather than editing it into the question - that will a) allow people to upvote it and b) you can mark it as "accepted" so that everyone knows it's the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have that lens. You can buy a M42 to Nikon F (not the opposite) adapter **with correction lens**, otherwise you lose the ability to focus at infinity.

The lens will lower the image quality, since you can only find cheap Chinese adapters with said correction lens.

The solution is (at your own risk) to remove the correction lens from the adapter, and also remove the "stop" screw in the MTO, the one that blocks the front part of the lens from being completely unscrewed and removed. Of course, you will have to be careful to avoid going too far when you focus, but it's easy to avoid issues.

I use it with D40, D7100. Recently I removed the last lenses (closest to the camera) that constitute a 1.4X focal multiplier. Now it's a 620mm (measured) lens, f/6.2 and much brighter. Basically it's equivalent to the original MTO used on a FF camera.

Answer (score 0):

MTO-11CA should go with M42. I suggest you using a caliper to check the mount ([M42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M42_lens_mount) means 42mm of diameter and 1mm of thread pitch).

I only heard of people unable to fit the lens, being too big and hitting the camera body, is it your case?

Comment: I don't have a caliper but I got 39mm with a ruler, so I need to find M39 adapter? And yea, it looks that it will hit the body

Comment: any answers? please help

Comment: I found with some searches that there are some MTO with M39 actually. But I suppose that even with a M39 to Nikon (or M39 to M42) you won't be able to use it. With some luck and a big adapter (or an extension tube) you'll be able to use the lens but without being able to focus infinity

Comment: So it wont work on nikon, right?

Comment: It depends on the shape of the camera body (flash protrusion mainly), some of them fit.
Here you can see a guy having it on a D700: https://www.flickr.com/photos/paulo007/3956666550/in/album-72157619416248727/

Answer (score 0):

You can find a KP AN adapter from Ex Russia . It will fit any Russian lens with A in the end of name. And is for Nikon.On Ebay is around 10 GBP.

Answer (score 0):

I use two adapters with mine. A 39 to 42 screw thread adapter, and then a 42 to Nikon.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples of the KP AN adapter. You can use most Soviet/Russian lenses with this which are M42 mount, preserving infinity focus:

English:

> 1. Jupiter-37A (135 / 3.5)
> 2. Tair-11A (135 / 2.8)
> 3. Mir-10A (28 / 3.5)
> 4. Mir-1A (37 / 2.8)
> 5. Industar-61A (50 / 2.8)
> 6. Jupiter-11A (135/4)
> 7. Jupiter-21A (200/4)
> 8. Tair-3A/3C (300 / 4.5)
> 9. ZM-4A (500 / 6.3)
> 10. ZM-5A (500/8)
> 11. ZM-6A (500 / 6.3)
> 12. MTO-500A (550 / 8.5)
> 13. MTO-11A (1000/10)
> 14. MTO-11SA (1000/10)
> 15. MTO 1000A (1100 / 10.5)

Russian:

> 1. Юпитер-37А (135/3.5)
> 2. Таир-11А (135/2,8)
> 3. Мир-10А (28/3.5)
> 4. Мир-1А (37/2,8)
> 5. Индустар-61А (50/2,8)
> 6. Юпитер-11А (135/4)
> 7. Юпитер-21А (200/4)
> 8. Таир-3А/3C (300/4.5)
> 9. 3М-4А (500/6.3)
> 10. 3М-5А (500/8)
> 11. 3М-6А (500/6.3)
> 12. МТО-500А (550/8.5)
> 13. МТО-11А (1000/10)
> 14. МТО-11СА (1000/10)
> 15. МТО-1000А (1100/10.5)

[image]

[image]

The title of the programmable chip adapter:

```
KP/AN (КП/АН) - Nikon F adapter with AF PROGRAMMABLE CHIP! Одуванчик Лушникова
```

From my understanding, the Lushnikov Dandelion is the chip. Victor Lushnikov being the creator. The adapter itself is made at the Arsenal factory in Kiev.